# SWT Combo and CCombo as CellEditor

Tags: java, combobox, swt, jface, tablecelleditor

[image: CCombo]

Why is the last item blank? I only have 3 items (it's a tri-state boolean editor).

---

[image: Combo1]

Can a `CCombo` achieve this solid `Combo` look and feel?

---

[image: Combo2]

As a combo cell editor, I would prefer the regular `Combo`, BUT: 
Can this `Combo` be used as `CellEditor`, while fitting the table row height? (maybe making the `Font` smaller?)

Comment: The default visible item count for `CCombo` is 5, try calling `setVisibleItemCount(3)`.

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you. Would you like to take a shot at the other two bullet points? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default visible item count for `CCombo` is 5, try calling `setVisibleItemCount(3)`.

`CCombo` does not support much customization. It always sets the same colors for the list and the text for example.

The look of `Combo` varies a lot between platforms, the Mac version might look odd in a table column. `Combo` does support setting the font but I don't know if that would work.