# Get rid of the extra line in my SWT ComboBoxCellEditor?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface, inline-editing

My SWT ComboBoxCellEditor has an extra line at the bottom[image: Extra line in ComboBoxCellEditor].

Is there any way to get rid of it? It's there no matter how many elements I have.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078512/swt-combo-and-ccombo-as-celleditor)

Comment: [Also this bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388126)

Comment: @Baz Thanks for the references. They were really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ComboBoxCellEditor` uses a `CCombo` widget for editing. With `CCombo#setVisibleItemCount()` the number of visible items can be controlled.

Depending on when you know how many items should be visble you can *configure* the combo box. For example through overriding `createControl`

```java
ComboBoxCellEditor editor = new ComboBoxCellEditor() {
  @Override
  protected Control createControl( Composite parent ) {
    CCombo combo = ( CCombo )super.createControl( parent );
    combo.setVisibleItemCount( 2 );
    return combo;
  }
};
```

Comment: As @Baz pointed out in his comment on the question, this is a known bug in Eclipse. I just set the visible item count to one less than the number of items I was showing, and it was fine. I didn't override createControl() - just did it in the same place I added the items.